# Count with conditions in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables (songs, albums and two relation tables).

I have this 2 queries that I need to merge:

-QUERY 1)

```
SELECT l.name_language, count(s.id_song) 
FROM language as l
LEFT JOIN song_has_languages as s ON l.id_language = s.id_language
GROUP BY l.id_language
HAVING COUNT(s.id_song) > 0
ORDER BY name_language ASC
```

The output:

```
name_language | songs 
English       | 5     
Spanish       | 1
```

-QUERY 2)

```
SELECT l.name_language, count(a.id_album) 
FROM language as l
LEFT JOIN album_has_languages as a ON l.id_language = a.id_language
GROUP BY l.id_language
HAVING COUNT(a.album)> 0
ORDER BY name_language ASC
```

The output:

```
name_language | albums
English       | 5
French        | 2
```

My goal is this output:

```
name_language | total | 
English       | 10    | 
Spanish       | 1     | 
French        | 2     |
```

I want to print only the languages with a song or an album.

Comment: The results from  your first query make no sense.  You have a `having` clause that would preclude `'French'`.  Similarly for the second query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you are right! I edited the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with `union all` and aggregation:

```
select l.name_language, sum(num_songs + num_albums) as total
from language l left join
     ((select shl.id_language, count(*) as num_songs, 0 as num_albums
       from song_has_languages shl
       group by  shl.id_language
      ) union all
      (select ahl.id_language, 0 as num_songs, count(*) as num_albums
       from album_has_languages ahl
       group by ahl.id_language
      )
     ) sa
     on sa.id_language = l.id_language
group by l.id_language, l.name_language;
```

You could also express this with `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select l.name_language,
       ( coalesce(num_songs, 0) + coalesce(num_albums, 0) ) as total
from language l left join
     (select shl.id_language, count(*) as num_songs
      from song_has_languages shl
      group by  shl.id_language
     ) shl 
     on shl.id_language = l.id_language left join
     (select ahl. id_language, count(*) as num_albums
      from album_has_languages ahl
      group by ahl.id_language
     ) ahl
     on ahl.id_language = l.id_language;
```